# No video, but i get sound - knockout.js Custom Binding with video.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, html5-video, video.js

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/rpallas/pen/AfJGh) / [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpallas/GgSEe/)

I have an app which uses next/previous buttons to cycle through a bunch of videos. I'm using knockout.js to control the UI so i created a custom binding that initialises a single video tag, and then when knockout moves to the next video, it updates an observable that holds an array of src objects `{src:"", type:""}`.

[Here is a codepen of the problem](http://codepen.io/rpallas/pen/AfJGh). Here, the first video has no audio (this is expected), but if you click "Next" and you have audio turned on, you should hear a sequence of beeps - which is the expected audio for the second video. But there is no video after the first one. Also if you try to go back to the first one it also doesn't work.

I've had this in the debug console, and everything appears to be ok with the video object in the `update' method of the customBinding - its source gets set correctly - but none of the methods seem to enable me to show the video.

I'm not sure if this is something i'm doing wrong with the knockout binding, or if i'm misunderstanding video.js somehow?

My customBinding looks like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.video = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var videoSources = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()).videos,
        playerId = allBindingsAccessor().playerId,
        options = { loop : true, controls: true, autoplay: true, preload: "auto" };

    videojs(playerId, options, function(){
        var video = this;
        video.src(videoSources).load().play();
    });
  },

  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var videoSources = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()).videos,
        playerId = allBindingsAccessor().playerId,
        video = videojs(playerId);

    video.pause().src(videoSources).load().play();
  }
};
```

And the markup:

```
<div id="assessmentIntroPanel" data-bind="with: currentStep">
  <div data-bind="video: videos, playerId: 'videoPlayer'">
    <video id="videoPlayer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="430" height="267">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have run into the same issue.

It appears if Knockout bindings ever remove video elements (even temporarily), it also breaks them.

This is fixed by making sure 'with' and 'if' bindings don't apply to a video.

With your code this would mean something like:

```
<div id="assessmentIntroPanel" data-bind="with: currentStep">
  <div data-bind="video: videos, playerId: 'videoPlayer'">

  </div>
</div>
<video id="videoPlayer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="430" height="267">
</video>
```

So your UI will be more complicated... but now as the video element is never removed it should work.